# Combine images and draw text on each image with animation xfade

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, images

I am using ffmpeg to merge multiple images and an audio to produce a video. I am using drawtext and xfade with dissolve transition. My ffmpeg command is given below.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img0.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img1.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img2.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img3.jpg -t 20 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex " 
[0]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20,setsar=1[v0];
[1]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20,setsar=1[v1];
[2]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20,setsar=1[v2];
[3]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20,setsar=1[v3];
[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 4:a -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

I am getting below error when executing this command.

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_xfade_9
```

What could be an issue in this command?

Comment: `[0][1]xfade...[v1];[v1][1]xfade...` and increase offset at every step 4,8,12

Comment: This works but now the audio is muted. How to enable the audio?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with below solution with the help of the comment. Posting it here for anyone else looking for the same solution.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img0.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img3.jpg \
-t 20 -stream_loop -1 -i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex  " \
[0]drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20[v0]; \
[1]drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20[v1]; \
[2]drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20[v2]; \
[3]drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20[v3]; \
[v0][v1]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,setsar=1[x1]; \
[x1][v2]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=8,setsar=1[x2]; \
[x2][v3]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=12,setsar=1[x3]" -map "[x3]" -map 4:a -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

It also works with the `concat` filter as below:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img0.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ./img/img3.jpg \
-t 20 -stream_loop -1 -i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex  " \
[0]drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20[v0]; \
[1]drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20[v1]; \
[2]drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20[v2]; \
[3]drawtext=fontfile='./Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf':text='Text1':fontcolor='#666333':fontsize=(h/30):x=50:y=20[v3]; \
[v0][v1]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=4,setsar=1[x1]; \
[x1][v2]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=8,setsar=1[x2]; \
[x2][v3]xfade=transition=dissolve:duration=1:offset=12,setsar=1[x3]; \
[x3]concat=n=1:v=1:a=0[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 4:a -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```